# Restore DB from SQL Server 2008 R2 to 2014 Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, restore, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to restore a database backup made in SQL Server 2008 R2 to the 2014 Express version. Is this even possible? If I choose restore from device and select my backup file, I see no database in the drop down.

Comment: Duplicate Post: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402637/can-we-restore-sql-server-2008r2-backup-on-sql-server-2014

Comment: Which database? Not master, model, msdb.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, as long as the database is < 10 GB and doesn't use any features not supported by Express (you didn't mention what edition was being used in 2008 R2).

Stop using the broken point-and-click UI, and instead use a proper [`RESTORE DATABASE` command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx):

```
RESTORE DATABASE DBFrom2008 FROM DISK = 'C:\backups\2008backup.bak'
  WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY,
  MOVE 'data_file_name' TO 'C:\...\database_name.mdf',
  MOVE 'log_file_name'  TO 'C:\...\database_name.ldf';
```

If you get errors from that (after replacing all of the obvious bits that are specific to your database and system), post those.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what edition. What you're doing is basically a side-by-side upgrade. See full list of supported upgrade paths at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393(v=sql.120).aspx